# How to display images in meteor

Tags: javascript, image, meteor

I am writing my code in (root-directory)/imports/ui/body.html and i have an img src tag there which is not working. After searching on the internet found out that we have to store assets in the public folder.After doing so , still i cannot get the image to be displayed.But when i use the image tag in client/main.html i am able to see the image , but not when i add the img src in body.html in imports/ui.

i have tried:

```
< img src="../../img.jpg" >
< img src="../../client/img.jpg" >
```

Answer (score 2):

If path for your images are `root/app/public/img.jpg` and `root/app/public/client/img.jpg`, the use this to access them:

```
<img src="/img.jpg" />
<img src="/client/img.jpg" />
```

Comment: and i am writing the code in root/imports/ui/body.html

Comment: how do you access your app? what is the url?

Comment: its local, om my pc

Comment: i do not know why it is happening but when i put my image in another html file in a template  ,then its working fine. :)

Comment: `/public` in your project directory maps to `/` in your app, regardless of what directory your html file is in.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder named "public" in the root directory of your app. Paths in your code will use this folder as the root directory. So putting your image file directly in "public" and accessing it using '/img.jpg' should work.